# Публикация ASP.NET Core приложения с MSSQL

Tags: c#, развертывание

На локалке сделал небольшой ASP.NET Core проект, с Базой данных MSSQL. Сейчас встал вопрос о его публикации в интернете, информации крайне мало.

VPS/VDS, на Windows Server почти никаких нет, если есть то за кучу денег.

В Azure сейчас залететь нельзя из России.
В соседней теме писали про deploy-f, заманчиво конечно, но там такие низкие характеристики за 600р.

И так же слышал что для корректной работы MSSQL надо минимум 2ГБ, т.е хостинг брать уже на 3ГБ. Короче огромная куча вопросов, сделать весь этот проект оказалось проще чем задеплоить его.

Comment: Посмотрите https://deploy2production.ru/, возможно, на часть вопросов получится ответы.

Comment: Вероятно, следует переписать приложение на использование другой СУБД. Это даст хорошее понимание, зачем нужны паттерн репозиторий, инъекция зависимостей, тестирование и пр. Если они есть, то миграция пройдёт быстро и гладко.

Comment: А зачем вообще Windows Server? .NET давно стал кроссплатформенным. Sql Server тоже. Так что можно хоститься на Linux.